# CLI limited when doing login with a user created

Tags: linux, debian, command-line-interface, vpn

In my VPS, I don't know why, but when I do a `su` to another user what I get is:

```
root@deb64:~# su john
$
```

The autocomplete with tab doesn't work, and even the command source. Example:

```
root@deb64:/home/john/myproject# source venv/bin/activate
(venv) root@deb64:/home/john/myproject#
```

---

```
root@deb64:/home/john/myproject# su john
$ cd /home/john/myproject
$ source venv/bin/activate
sh: 2: source: not found
$
```

What is happening with the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switching into a shell which does not have tab-completion (`sh` for instance). You can start `bash` or similar like this: `exec bash`. You can edit `/etc/passwd` if you wish to make this permanent.